# ReactJS: How to additional set of images in grid?

Tags: javascript

Not using any CSS frameworks, what would be the right approach to doing this? I had `<ul>` in mind.

Thank you and will upvote + accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Provide an array of the img urls as a prop in your component.

Store the number of images grids in local state and initialize it with 1.

In your render method output the current state amount (this.state.imgGridCount) of images.

The load more button should call a function which in turn calls setState to increment the current number by 1. React should automatically render 8 images now (or 12 when clicked twice).

Comment: Do you mind showing a rough example of it for clarification?

Comment: Before I accept the answer and upvote. Please let me know if you've seen my previous comment.